# Partially relative date and time using Android DateUtils

Tags: android, date, formatting

I am trying to format timestamps in a partially relative format: today, tomorrow or the weekday for the day; time always in absolute hh:mm. Example:

- Monday 11:00
- Tomorrow 10:30

Timestamps are always in the future and always less than a week from today.

I have tried the following:

```
DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(context, date.getTime(),
    DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,
    DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS,
    DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_WEEKDAY | DateUtils.FORMAT_NO_MONTH_DAY);
```

However, this gives me weird things such as “in 19 hours, 12:00” or “in 3 days, 11:00”.

I have tried changing the `transitionResolution` (4th) argument. However, neither `DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS`, nor `DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS` nor plain `0` changed anything, at least for a point in time past midnight, but less than 24 h in the future.

I’d prefer to avoid third-party libraries, and I would also rather not roll my own (as that is almost guaranteed to fail for at least one corner case I have not considered).

Any way of getting timestamps formatted as described above?